# Enable PDO in shared server

Tags: apache-2.2, pdo, apache-1.3

My newest client has decided (against my heavy recommendation to use my tried and true host..) to use Webmasters.com to host their site.

This is turning into a nightmare... I finally got the full access I needed instead of a child-lock account (couldn't even access root folder people..).

So I finally got the client to cough up the necessary info and put the files on the server just to find: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{`, which works fine on localhost. The line that the function fails on is a try block, so I'm guessing PDO isn't working right. Here's the php.ini pdo data.

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=libpdf_php.so
extension=pfpro.so
```

Also, the server is Apache 1.x instead of 2.x, but there's an upgrade option. Is this the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution was to upgrade to Apache 2.x**

Once I did, PDO worked like a charm. I'm not sure why webmasters.com hosting is running Apache 1.x by default, but given their control panel it doesn't surprise me.